# How can I use Rust to CLONE a linked list?

Tags: rust

I'm a rookie in Rust, and currently I'm actively using Rust to code LeetCode practice.

Now I'm working on this one, [Copy List with Random Pointer](https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer/), where nobody has even provided a Rust version answer.

I tried for a while but then I realised it's insanely hard for me to copy **even a simple linked list** in Rust.

Thanks for the help from @cafce25 that we can directly use `.clone()` to implement it, which is amazing. However, I'm wondering if there is any implementation that we don't need to use such a mighty weapon `.clone()` so that I could delve from this point.

Could anyone give me a favour? Thank you pretty much.

Some interfaces are provided as below and please feel free to modify function signatures.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode {
            val,
            next: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn copyList(head: &Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

Comment: just `head.clone()` no semicolon, should work for the problem described in the question... if you're interested you can use `cargo-expand` to look what the derived `Clone` looks like. But the linked problem and the one described here are different.

Comment: @cafce25 Oh thank you. I thought `clone()` only copy one node but I was wrong. I just did an experiment and found that the entire list was cloned.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I'm wondering if there is any implementation that we don't need to use such a mighty weapon .clone() so that I could delve from this point.

First of all, it seems reasonable for `copyList` to actually take a reference to a list node itself, and the more idiomatic name is `copy_list`:

```
    pub fn copy_list(head: &ListNode) -> ListNode {
        todo!()
    }
```

(no `;` at the end because we want to return a result, and the semicolon would make the function return `()`). The first step is (not necessarily, but it's useful) to pattern-match the argument, and we also know we want to return a `ListNode` at the end, so let's construct it there:

```
    pub fn copy_list(head: &ListNode) -> ListNode {
        let ListNode { val, next } = head;
        let copied_next = todo!();
        ListNode { val: todo!(), next: copied_next }
    }
```

What remains is to calculate `copied_next` (ok, and `val`, but it's much simpler). I won't give you the full code for it, but some hints:

1. Consider the types of `next` and `copied_next`;
2. You can use either pattern matching on `next` or `Option::map` and `Box::map`;
3. You'll call `copy_list` recursively somewhere inside that pattern match or `map`'s argument.

(And simply `next.clone()` would work too, and is approximately what the generated `clone()` function does, which is *why* it clones the entire list.)

Comment: Thank you so much. With your precious hints, I've provided a solution as the 2nd answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inspiration from @Alexey Romanov. After several hours of debugging, I implemented a plain way to clone a linked list as below:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode {
            val,
            next: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn clone_linked_list(mut head: &Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        let mut dummy = Box::new(ListNode::new(-1));
        let mut pre = &mut dummy; 
        while let Some(node) = head {
            let new_node = Box::new(ListNode::new(node.val));
            pre.next.replace(new_node);
            pre = pre.next.as_mut().unwrap();
            head = &node.next;
        }
        dummy.next
    }
}
```

Please feel free to give any suggestions. Thank you a lot.